# Bitwise Comparison of char and unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, comparison, bit-manipulation

Why isnt there a bit-wise comparator like "====" in C++? Do i have to cast variables each time?

(note: i already know logical-arithmetic operators, looking a different thing. By the way there is not arithmetic-xor a^^b also :) 
I know i can check a&b against a(or b), a^b against zero,...
)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a=-1;
    unsigned char b=0;

    for(b=0;b<255;b++)
    {
        if(a==b)std::cout<<(int)b;  //cannot find 11111111)2==11111111)2
                                    //ok, it looks -1==255 surely 
                  //if(a====b)std::cout<<" bitwise equal "; could be good
    }



    bool compare=true;
    bool bit1=false,bit2=false;
    unsigned char one=1;

    b=255; //bit-swise equal to a
    for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
    {
        bit1=(a>>i)&one;
        bit2=(b>>i)&one;
        if(bit1!=bit2){compare=false;return;}//checks if any bit is different 
    }

    if(compare)std::cout<<(int)b; //this writes 255 on screen

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

I could have done:

```
__asm
     {
          push push....
          mov al,[a]
          mov dl,[b]
          cmp al,dl    //this is single instr but needs others
          je yes       
          mov [compare],false
          jmp finish
          yes:
          mov [compare],true
          jmp finish

          finish:
          pop pop...
```

Bloated code...

Comment: What should be the result of '7 === 4'?

Comment: 7====4 false because being not equal  bit-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
a ^ b == 0
```

Comment: I know this but i look for a single thing like a====b

Comment: It doesn't exist, and frankly is not needed, you should do it as I suggested.

Comment: This will still promote both values, and may yield `false` even if both have the same bit pattern. I think it's equivalent to `a == b`, just more obscure.

Comment: @Mike Seymour is your last statement true?

Comment: Yes it is. For example, try `unsigned char a = 0xff;` and `signed char b = 0xff`. Assuming `int` is larger than `char`, and signed arithmetic uses twos-complement, then they will be promoted to `0x00ff` and `0xffff` which will not appear equal using either `==` or `^`. This answer is only useful if you want to obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 2):

Such an operator would not work, because it would be platform dependent.

I assume that 'x === y' should return false when x and y have different lengths, and since int has different lengths on different platforms, so would the result of this operation.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to compare signed to unsigned?

You should redesign your algorithm to make both operands of `==` to have the same signedness.

Comment: When i go far in a project, sometimes changing a single variable affects many

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: It is still a design and not a language issue

Comment: Or define what he wants to compare.  `unsigned char` is typically used
for "raw memory", and there are cases where it might make sense to see
if a byte in raw memory corresponds to a specific character.  (The issue
should be simple, but isn't, because the standard allows plain `char` to
behave as if it were signed.  Which means that something like `'é'` may
have a negative value, and never compare equal to an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do any comparisons on `char` or `unsigned char`.  Integral
promotion means that the smallest integral type you can compare is
`int`; both the `char` and the `unsigned char` will be promoted to `int`
before the comparison.  (After which, on most modern machines, there
will be no difference between bitwise comparison and value comparison.)

I'm tempted to say that you shouldn't want bit-wise comparison.  In many
ways, the implicit conversions (including the promotions) cause more
problems than anything else, and logically, you *should* have to be
explicit, and specify what you want to compare.  (And the tests for
equality are guaranteed to be "big-wise" if the type is `unsigned char`.
This is why `memcmp` is defined in terms of `unsigned char`
comparisons.)

Comment: When char(-1) promoted what it is in int? and unsigned char(255) ?

Comment: Implementation defined.  If plain `char` is signed, `char(-1)` is -1; if plain `char` is unsigned, `char(-1)` is 2^n-1, where n is the number of bits in `char`---255 on most modern machines.  (`unsigned char(255)` is, of course, 255.)

Comment: Then both of them promoted to int and one of them -1 the other one is 255 which are not same

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Both are promoted to int, without changing their value, but the value of `char(-1)` is implementation defined, and could be positive.